# Horizontal view swiping with tabs

Tags: android, view, tabs, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

I made a bet with one of my teachers and I need to make an app which accesses the school's website.I added a TabBar which has 3 `WebView`s, like so:
[image]

Now I want to be able to swipe between those tabs. I tried to add a `HorizontalScrollView` but had no success, then I found something about implementing a `ViewPager`, I think this is the solution but I just can't make it work.

The activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_gravity="start|top">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                        <WebView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/webView" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <WebView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/webView2"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <WebView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/webView3" />

                    </LinearLayout>


            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</FrameLayout>
   
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.smash.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and a piece from the MainActivity.java:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://schoolwebsite/");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Home");
        tabSpec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        tabSpec1.setIndicator("Home");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec1);

        mWebView2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView2.loadUrl("http://schoolwebsite");
        mWebView2.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Teachers");
        tabSpec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        tabSpec2.setIndicator("Teachers");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec2);

        mWebView3 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView3);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView3.loadUrl("http:/schoolwebsite");
        mWebView3.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Students");
        tabSpec3.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        tabSpec3.setIndicator("Students");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec3);
        // Set up the drawer.

 mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp( R.id.navigation_drawer,(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    }
```

Ow, almost forgot to mention that I created my app using the built-in Navigation Drawer Activity provided by the Android Studio.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: It is deprecated dont use that, use sliding tabs like google play .You can check devbytes videos in youtube for example.

Comment: Interesting, I'm gonna watch some of their videos maybe I'll manage to do it.

Comment: I downloaded their SlidingTabBasic sample, looked into it then I tried to combine it with my app, but had no luck.